# Display number of font awesome star icons depends on value in database column

Tags: php, mysqli, fonts, font-awesome, rating-system

Im sorry, but Im new to this.

I have a number of products that I want to display from a database. One of the columns is rating.

I want to know how to display the value from that column as font awesome star icons instead of the value itself.

Each product's value (1 to 5) is entered by the admin, and displayed as filled stars for the visitor (x number out of 5).
I also want to show the average value of all products as stars (where one star can be partially filled.).

This project using php and mysqli.

Grateful for help!

Comment: This site is purposed for receiving assistance in programming where you present your non-working code requesting assistance in correcting the code. It is not purposed to have code written for you. Please provide your non-working code as a starting point where assistance can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any star rating jquery plugin : https://phppot.com/jquery/favorite-star-rating-with-jquery/

> **Style**

```
li{display: inline-block;color: #F0F0F0;text-shadow: 0 0 1px #666666;font-size:30px;}
.highlight, .selected {color:#F4B30A;text-shadow: 0 0 1px #F48F0A;}
```

> **HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="rating" id="rating" />
<ul onMouseOut="resetRating();">
  <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">★</li>
  <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">★</li>
  <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">★</li>
  <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">★</li>
  <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this);" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this);">★</li>
</ul>
```

> **Scripts**

```
function highlightStar(obj) {
    removeHighlight();      
    $('li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
        if(index == $("li").index(obj)) {
            return false;   
        }
    });
}

function removeHighlight() {
    $('li').removeClass('selected');
    $('li').removeClass('highlight');
}

function addRating(obj) {
    $('li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('#rating').val((index+1));
        if(index == $("li").index(obj)) {
            return false;   
        }
    });
}

function resetRating() {
    if($("#rating").val()) {
        $('li').each(function(index) {
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            if((index+1) == $("#rating").val()) {
                return false;   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Demo link :** https://phppot.com/demo/dynamic-star-rating-with-php-and-jquery/

You just need to dynamic this in PHP that's all.

Reference Here is the tutorial to make star rating dynamic : 
https://phppot.com/jquery/dynamic-star-rating-with-php-and-jquery/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22497718)

Comment: Will do next time